# The import org cannot be resolved (json)

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I am trying to use json, and I have added it to my classpath in Eclipse with

`properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs...`

However, I get the error:

`The import org cannot be resolved`

On the following line:

`import org.json.JSONObject;`

The stack trace says:

> Error: Unable to initialize main class iTunesPackage.iTunes in module module iTunes
>   Caused by: module iTunes: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Every solution on StackOverflow says to add the external JAR, which I have already done, which is why I am confused. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: can you browse (Java browsing view) your project and see if the jar is indeed listed, and then expand the packages to see it contains the package as you have used in your import statement? Eclipse has these kind of bugs so you may also try and restart your eclipse to check if problem persists.

Comment: It is indeed there under "Referenced Libraries"

Comment: What exactly is under _Referenced Libraries_? Maybe you added the wrong JAR containing the sources (`*.java` files) or Javadoc (`*.html` files) instead of the bytecode (`*.class` files).

Comment: @MohamedElgharbawy Can you post a screenshot of your "Configure Build Path" window in eclipse to your question?

Comment: @Abhinav See my answer, it turns out it was an issue with the packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to move the file to my default package, rather than a package I had created myself. This fixed all the issues!